# Performance logging for a live test?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, logging, monitoring

We are completing our application, written in PHP/MySQL (+ memcached) and we are going to start, next weekend, a live test for one night (it's a sort of "social" application).

We will, of course, monitor error log files to make sure everything went fine. But we would like also to keep logs of the performance of the application: for example, determine if a script ran too slow, and more in details how long it took for functions/methods to run, for MySQL queries to be executed and compare that with data obtained (and "un-jsoned") from memcached.

This is the first time I'm doing something like this: however, I believe it's fundamental because we need to make sure the application will scale correctly when our customers will start using it in 10-15 days. (Up)scaling will not be a big issue, since we are using cloud servers (we will start with a single instance with 256 MB of RAM, provided by a well-known company), but we would like to be sure resources are used efficiently.

Do you have any suggestion for this monitoring? Good practices? Good articles to read?

Also, when the test is over, should we continue to monitor performances on the live environment? Even if not on all requests, but just on a sample?

PS: Is it a good idea to log on a file all MySQL queries and the time they took to run?

Comment: For MySQL you could start by enabling the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html). Note that any kind of extra monitoring will to a small extent reduce performance.

Comment: "Scaling will not be a big issue, since we are using cloud servers" --- hehe, if it was only so simple as you think ;-)

Comment: Well, during the initial live test I would like to monitor *everything*, not just slow queries... I know it will impact performances, but at least at the beginning I would like to have all the information possible.

Comment: @zermks: I meant "upscaling" sorry :)

Comment: It's a paid service, but I've heard wonderful things about [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/)

Comment: I wonder why the -2 without explanations....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually unit test my work so I can make sure its running at a satisfactory speed, giving the right results, etc.

Once I've finished unit testing I will stress test it, I run the most commonly used functions through an insane loop from my local machine and an instance I have set up for brutally testing my applications and since my tests are written in PHP I can log anything i like;

Such as performance, but I would never use it live I'd just be sure I'm confident with what I have written

[EDIT]

Do you use Zend Studio? (that's the PHP IDE I use) because it has built in unit testing, you can get a free trial here which when it ends is still very functional, I have the paid version so I'm not sure if unit testing is still viable but its well worth its buck!

Here's a link that [introduces unit testing](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2772) which is really great and you can grab the trial of Zend Studio [here](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads)

here are a few more links for unit testing just pulled from Google.

[lastcraft.com](http://www.lastcraft.com/first_test_tutorial.php)
[List of unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks)
[Another Stack Overflow post on unit testing PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842/best-way-to-implement-unit-testing-in-php)
[Google results page](http://tinyurl.com/6gfdlum)

Comment: I've never done unit testing with PHP. Can you please link me some articles? Speaking of software to use, I found this one: [phpunit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/). What about it?

Comment: No, I use Coda (for OSX). Do you have articles about unit testing with PHP?

Comment: There are 4 links in the edits for tutorials/posts I just pulled them from Google.

Comment: Sorry, I was with my mobile phone and didn't noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could look at installing something like this on the machine(s):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacti_%28software%29

It's always handy to have current and historical information about the performance of you system (CPU\Mem\Bandwidth).